# Matlab, AppDesigner-Convert image on a good type and use it in "imread" function

Tags: arrays, matlab, types, type-conversion, cell

I use AppDesigner inMATLAB to show photos with changed RGB. But there is the problem with character of the photo.

1. When I switch on my own fuction "changeRGB", finally "choosenImage" has 20bytes, class "char" and size(1x10). OK!
2. There is no problem in using the "function OpenButtonValueChanged". OK!
3. There is the problem with "function UploadButtonPushed". OK!

ABOUT THE PROBLEM:
When I click button which callback is "function UploadButtonPushed" I get the error: 
"Error using imread>parse_inputs (line 502)
The file name or URL argument must be a character
vector or string scalar."

"Error in imread (line 342)
[source, fmt_s, extraArgs, was_cached_fmt_used] =
parse_inputs(cached_fmt, varargin{:});"

WHY?
Because in the "function UploadButtonPushed" my choosenImage has 1977624bytes, class "uint8" and size(681x968x3). So it's too bug for "imread".

WHAT I TRIED:

- When in "function OpenButtonValueChanged" I convert a photo, adding "char":  (myimage = char(app.clickedImage)); the class of the photo is changing from uint8 to char but the size.
- When I use "num2cell", the claas of the photo is changing on "cell" but size and number of bytes are the same- so big. And I get the Error: "Error using imread>parse_inputs (line 502) The file name or URL argument must be a character vector or string scalar."

In my own function "changeRGB" I used "imread(image)" and here is the problem with the size of the photo. Do you know how to get the correct one?

```
%my own properties in AppDesigner- to use them in different functions 
properties (Access = public)
    clickedImage;
    addR = 1;
    addG = 1;
    addB = 1;
end

%first function in AppDeesigner
function OpenButtonValueChanged(app, event)
        value = app.OpenButton.Value;
        [file, howManyFiles] = chooseImagesFromComputer; %myown function

        %I load 3 images which are showed as miniatures
        myFile1 = imread(file{1});
        imshow(myFile1, 'Parent', app.UIAxes1_1);
        myFile2 = imread(file{2});
        imshow(myFile2, 'Parent', app.UIAxes1_2);
        myFile3 = imread(file{3});
        imshow(myFile3, 'Parent', app.UIAxes1_3);


        %take values of changed RGB from the slider
        app.addR = app.SliderR.Value
        app.addG = app.SliderG.Value
        app.addB = app.SliderB.Value

        %work only on one image to change its colors. app.clickedImage, app.addR, app.addG, app.addB are properties at the beginning of the code
        app.clickedImage = file{1};
        app.clickedImage = changeRGB(app.clickedImage,app.addR,app.addG,app.addB); %changeRGB- my own function- here is the problem. I add it bottom
        imshow(app.clickedImage,'Parent',app.UIAxesMain);
    end

%second function in AppDesigner
%here is the button to upload color of the photo
function UploadButtonPushed(app, event)
        myimage = app.clickedImage;
        myimage = changeRGB(myimage,app.addR,app.addG,app.addB);
        imshow(myimage);
    end


%here is my own function in matlab, not in AppDesigner, which makes problem:
function [changedImage] = changeRGB(choosenImage, addR, addG, addB)
 whos
 loadedImage = imread(choosenImage);

 R = loadedImage(:,:,1); %extract one of the color channels
 G = loadedImage(:,:,2);
 B = loadedImage(:,:,3);
 RBG = cat(3,R,G,B);

 R_adj2 = R + addR;
 G_adj2 = G + addG;
 B_adj2 = B + addB;
 changedImage = cat(3,R_adj2,G_adj2,B_adj2);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you make unnecessary operations in `changeRGB`

```
function [changedImage] = changeRGB(choosenImage, addR, addG, addB)
   loadedImage = imread(choosenImage);
   loadedImage = bsxfun(@sum, loadedImage, reshape([addR, addG, addB], [1 1 3]);
end
```

Then this function return an array (the modified image) so in `UploadButtonPushed(app, event)` when you run `myimage = app.clickedImage;`, you are passing the modified array instead of the image path, that you set here `app.clickedImage = changeRGB(app.clickedImage,app.addR,app.addG,app.addB);`

So you have to change the design of your variables, because app.clickedImage is saving either the image path, or the image itself. Consider having 2 different variables.

A good advice also is to use [matlab debugger](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html) which is really good help to find the source of this kind of problems.

Comment: I have 8bit file and want to change it and use "num2cell" and "char" but the size of photos and number of bytes which they save are too big.

Comment: using num3cell on image seems a very bad idea. What do you mean by change RGB, in your question ?

Comment: I have a photo. "An RGB image, sometimes referred to as a truecolor image, is stored as an m-by-n-by-3 data array that defines red, green, and blue color components for each individual pixel." --> from this page: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/image-types.html I want to change numbers in arrays which define red, green and blue color

Comment: So basically, you want to create a custom image. Don't use cell, just work on the array outputed by imread. red = I(:,:,1), blue = I(:,:,2), green = I(:,:,3)

Comment: Yeah, I work on them, as you see in the last function, which is called "changeRGB". But I want to load picture through writing the name of the file, like 'myImage.jpg' and it's necessery to use "imread"

Comment: I want to change colors of my image

Comment: if it solve your problem, as it seems to, please consider accepting the answer!